# A question about Fourier transform of measures

Tags: measure-theory, fourier-analysis, representation-theory, harmonic-analysis

Let $G$ be a locally compact abelian group and $M(G)$ the Banach space of all complex Radon measures on $G$. The convolution on $M(G)$ is defined by specifying a linear functional on $C_0(G)$ (and invoking Riesz representation theorem) as follows: $$\int_G\phi\,\mathrm{d}(\mu*\nu)=\int_G\int_G\phi(xy)\,\mathrm{d}\mu(x)\,\mathrm{d}\nu(y),\text{ for }\phi\in C_0(G).$$

My question is:

> Why does it continue to hold for $\phi\in C_b(G)$, the space of bounded continuous functions on $G$?

I don't know how to approximate $C_b(G)$ from $C_0(G)$... Thanks in advance!

Edit: The same equality for $C_b(G)$ is needed to establish that $\widehat{\mu*\nu}=\widehat{\mu}*\widehat{\nu}$, where $\phi\in\widehat{G}$.

Note that complex measures are by definition finite.

Comment: Choose $K$ compact such that $|\mu |(K^{c}) <\epsilon $ and $|\nu | (K^{c}) <\epsilon $ There exits $\psi \in C_0(G)$ such that $|\psi|$ is bounded by the sup of $\phi$ and $\psi =\phi $ on $K$. Rest should be clear.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I'm stuck on the part $|\mu|(K^c)<\epsilon$. Why does $K$ exist? ($G$ is not necessarily $\sigma$-compact)

Comment: If $d\mu(x) = f(x)dx,d\nu(x) = g(x)dx$ are Radon measures then $\phi \ast f(x) = \int_G \phi(xy^{-1})f(y)dy$ is continuous for any $\phi \in C^0_c(G)$ but $(\phi \ast f) \ast g$ isn't well-defined in general. So you need that $\nu$ is a finite measure to ensure it works. Your linear functional is $\phi \mapsto ((\phi \ast f) \ast g)(0)$

Comment: @reuns See my edit.

Comment: @Colescu Since $|\mu|$ is  a finite Radon measure you can approximate the measure of $G$ by that of a compact set. (Radon usually means regular).

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Oh I see... Thanks.